# Need advice for making a fixed-spacing font for html5 annotation canvas application

Tags: css, html, fonts, letter-spacing

I know trying for fixed-display is usually a web design no-no, but please hear me out!

I'm developing a whiteboard-like addition to the forum I run. Long-story-short, the idea is that a user can type up their posts with text and bbcode like normal, then instatiate a managed canvas on top of their text, doodle on it with their mouse, hit submit, and then the doodle will show up on top of their post. The server processes the image into a transparent-background png and then aligns it properly into the text.

So I actually have the backend processing and the front-end interface all working well together. The only part left to do is the display, in which the processed doodle is aligned on top of the text. And, for this to work, the alignment of the image on the text needs to be pretty precise. If the user, say, circles or crosses-out a word, and the text isnt rendered in the same way for another user, the end-result is gonna be wrong. So, I figure that I need to get the text-display locked down.  This is kind of annoying, because right now everything is pretty fluid, but hey, this will be a pretty cool feature, right?  So, I've fixed the width of the post-display box, but I'm stumped as to what to do about the font - how to set the size, face, letter-spacing, line-spacing, etc so the display is as fixed as possible for different users on different monitors on different computers.

Does anyone have any ideas?  If it helps, I'm not at all concerned with IE or mobile displays...

Answer (score 0):

Kerning is going to be your biggest issue,but it should be easy enough by looking at the monospaced fonts available for font-face on fontsquirrel, something like this should do it

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/CPMono_v07

monospaced fonts should have equal letterspacing.

You can get finer control using letter-spacing:, line-height: and font-size: css classes

hope that's some help.